# How to show that the given configuration satisfies steady-state hydrodynamic equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, fluid-statics

[image]

In the figure shown, it is said that, at $z=0$, an interface separates two different fluids, having $\rho$ and $\rho'$ densities and also have uniform velocities $U$ and $U'$ in the x-direction. Also, both fluids are incompressible and ideal. There is also gravity acting in the negative $z$ direction.

Then, it is stated in the textbook that, this configuration satisfies the steady state hydrodynamic equation. I don't understand how to prove this statement. I know the steady state hydrodynamic ($\partial/\partial t = 0$) is

$$
\mathbf{(v \cdot \nabla) v} = - \dfrac{\nabla P}{\rho} + \mathbf{F}
$$

Since the fluid has uniform velocity, LHS is zero, which gives us $\dfrac{\nabla P}{\rho} = \mathbf{F}$. But how does this proves that the configuration satisfies the steady state equation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks pretty much how Kelvin-Helmholtz instability arises (different density fluids resting on top of each other moving at different speeds), so I'm not really sold on it having a steady state.

Comment: Yes it is the same. But the textbook stated that - This given configuration is in hydrodynamic steady state and can be verified easily. Bt how do we verify it? I did stuff up there... but how to proceed further?